# Will I need to clear US customs twice?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I'm flying to Lubbock in Texas in September. I can get flights with a 2 hour 25 min layover in Newark, or a 3 hour layover in Chicago.

However, from there I have to get a connecting flight to Houston. The most I can find is a 50 minute layover there before boarding the flight to Lubbock. Will I have to go through customs at Houston as well?

If so, I guess I'll need a longer layover there?

Comment: Is this all booked on the same ticket? If you have to change airlines and/or terminals, collect and recheck your bag and/or need to go through security again, 50 minutes may still be tight even if there is no immigration or customs.

Comment: It's all booked through united. I would prefer to have a bit more time as well, but I can't unfortunately :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you will pass through customs and immigration *once* upon your first arrival in the US (Newark, or Chicago). Your next flight to Houston will be a domestic flight with no customs procedure upon arrival in Houston.